# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, attributes, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Does anybody have any idea why this code doesn't work?

```
import turtle
test = turtle.Turtle()
test.color("orange")
test.pensize(5)
test.shape("turtle")
test.forward(100)
```

I use python 3.8

Comment: This works in Python2.7 but not in Python3.7. I haven't found the exact reason why yet.

What version of Python are you using?

Comment: the latest version (3.8)

Answer (score 65):

You've made a common error that I happended to also make when I was investigating your question.

I assume you have your code written in a file called '*turtle.py*'? When you import turtle, it imports your file, not the turtle library.

**Rename your file to something other than turtle.py, and your code should run fine.**

Here is the result when I renamed my file from *turtle.py* to *turtle2.py*.

[image: Turtle]

Answer (score -1):

You need to end the loop that draws on the screen, by typing :

```
turtle.done()
```

Comment: That could be just a comment

Comment: This doesn't match the error message given in the title. `turtle.Turtle()` is causing the problem.