# Can't seem to get turtle graphics to work on VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, turtle-graphics

I basically can't seem to be able to make turtle work for me. It always prompts errors that the names are not available.
My current issue which I can't seem to solve is that I get the Error:

> Cannot import 'Screen' from partially initialized module 'turtle'
> (most likely due to a circular import).

I am just using a simple code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle ()

turtle.forward(100)

screen.mainloop()

turtle.done()
```

I would love some ideas on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Your source file is called `turtle.py` - rename it to something different

Comment: @HandsomeBanana -As ForceBru said, when we use the file name "turtle.py", it imports the file instead of the turtle library. The problem can be solved after the name is changed.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Clmany thanks.

Comment: Hello! Would this help? [AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480328/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-turtle-has-no-attribute-turtle)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.forward(100)
screen.mainloop()
turtle.done()
```

If you want to look at other things in the library [click here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)