# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Can anyone tell me why this code dosen't work?

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen
for x in range(100):
    t.forward(x)
    t.left(90)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Is this script itself named `turtle.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480328/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-turtle-has-no-attribute-turtle)

Comment: This is a classic turtle/Python gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

File name issues aside, this code won't run due to missing parentheses after `Pen`.  Instead try:

```
import turtle

p = turtle.Pen()

for x in range(100):
    p.forward(x)
    p.left(90)

turtle.done()
```